# Game Center crash in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, game-center

My game has been working perfectly fine in iOS5 for a year.  After updating it to work with iOS6 it now crashes when attempting to send scores in Game Center.  It crashes on the `reportScoreWithCompletionHandler` line in the code

```
- (void)sendScore:(GKScore *)score {
    [score reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                       {
                           if (error == NULL) {
                               NSLog(@"Successfully sent score!");
                               [scoresToReport removeObject:score];                
                           } else {
                               NSLog(@"Score failed to send... will try again later.  Reason: %@", error.localizedDescription);                
                           }
                       });
    }];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

Having looked about a bit it seems there may also be an issue with `authenticateWithCompletionHandler`... My code for that is below.. If this is to blame how can I update it so it works?

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser { 

    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

    NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {     
        [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/41948)

It seems you have to create a copy of the score and submit the copy.  It only seems to happen when resending a saved score.  This may be because it tries to prevent you sending a `GKScore` from a leaderboard?

```
// Pull the score value and category from the passed in score
int scoreValue = score.value;
NSString*scoreCategory = score.category;

// Create a new temporary score with these values
GKScore *toReport = [[[GKScore alloc]
initWithCategory:scoreCategory] autorelease];
toReport.value = scoreValue;
```

Comment: Yes I had the same problem and that was the fix.